# Clarification of terminology: what is meant by a stochastic process conditioned to have property $P$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, definition

I came across the phrase "let $G_t$ be a Gaussian process conditioned to be positive".

My literal interpretation of this from English is that $G_t$ is a Gaussian process such that $G_t>0$ for each $t$. But I am also aware of the definition of the conditional expectation of a random variable with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra, although I have not seen what is meant by a a stochastic process conditioned to possess some property $P$.

Can someone clarify what is the precise meaning of "let $G_t$ be a Gaussian process conditioned to be positive"?

Comment: Hi: conditioned, in this particular context has ZERO to do with conditioning in the probabilistic sense. They could have just used "Gaussian process  made to be positive" and the meaning would be the same. I could see how the use of the term "condition" could cause confusion for not native english speakers.